# VS 2008 C++ Debugger works only once

Tags: c++, debugging

After a Windows update yesterday, I've run into a terrible problem. The debugger suddenly is creating issues.

When I bring up Visual Studio from the start menu, the debugger appears to start, but there is no console window and nothing happens for a long time.

But, if I start it from the VS command prompt, it works, *but only once*. This is become a nasty issue, and any help/pointers are highly appreciated.

Note: This problem happens with all the C++ projects on my system.

Comment: Could it be anything to do with loading debug symbols?  I'm on VS2005, but that has made start times terribly slow sometimes.

Comment: Hi,
If I bring up VS from the VS command prompt by typing devenv, and start the debbugger, it's starts pretty quickly. But, if I go to the "Start Menu" and start Visual Studio, I have problems. What happens is that, it says "Running" and I see that the output window changes, but nothing happens after that. There is no console debug window that comes up when you start the debugger.

Comment: That's only a problem if you have more than one bug....

Answer (score 1):

A quick work around would be to start without debugging, `ctrl + F5` I believe. If the same thing keeps happening it will be easier to pinpoint what is wrong. Also additional information about what is not working would be helpful.

Comment: I shall try that Jordan. In the meantime, I looked more into the issue. I see that the process that am trying to start does not come up fully and the debugger just waits there trying to attach to the process. Also, I cannot use the breakpoints as VS says that the source is different even though I did a clean build.